# Content between two span class

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse out a HTML page using beautiful soup and save it as smaller HTML files. I have two questions:
1. Is there a way that I can get content between two spans, for example:

```
<SPAN CLASS="c7">Q2 2016 Apple Inc Earnings Call - Final</SPAN>  I am feeling lucky today         <SPAN CLASS="c7">Event Brief of Q1 2016 Apple Inc Earnings Call - Final</SPAN>
```

I am looking to pull the text 'I am feeling lucky today' and save it as

Q2 2016 Apple Inc Earnings Call - Final.html

I have been playing around beautifulsoup but couldn't figure out a way to achieve this. Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Have you tried using regular expressions or simple string split operations?

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37579220/parsing-html-with-python-and-dumping-it-in-csv). @Rvs, if you want, you can ask a moderator to merge your two accounts. Don't forget to go through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to understand how stackoverflow works. The [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) provides many good hints that will improve your chances of getting good answers by being more complete in your questions. Check it out.

Comment: It is very easy in your example html but without seeing what else is there it is impossible to know

Comment: Thank you so much I will certainly do that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import re

text= '''<SPAN CLASS="c7">Q2 2016 Apple Inc Earnings Call - Final</SPAN> I am feeling lucky today     <SPAN CLASS="c7">Event Brief of Q1 2016 Apple Inc Earnings Call - Final</SPAN>'''
text2= '<span></span>You<span>Hola</span>Hey<span></span>'
pattern = '</(?:SPAN|span)>(?P<content>[\w\d\s]*)<(?:SPAN|span)'

print(re.findall(pattern, text))
print(re.findall(pattern, text2))
```

Using regular expressions, you can find all content between span tags and print it out at once. Above, I have tested this with both your example and one of my own.